# Postgres: column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query which is to do SUM aggregations on a column and select the column called `year` as it is,
**But I am getting an error -**

```
SQL Error [42803]: ERROR: column "snapshot.year" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
  Position: 211
```

**Following is my query -**

```
select 
'2019-09-11' as snapshot_date, 
SUM(case when snapshot_date = '2019-09-11' then balance end) as opening_balance,
SUM(case when snapshot_date = '2019-09-09' then balance end) as closing_balance,
year 
from snapshot
```

**DDL -**

```
CREATE TABLE snapshot (
    id bigserial NOT NULL,
    user_id int8 NOT NULL,
    latest_transaction_id int8 NOT NULL,
    wor_balance numeric(15,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
    last_transaction_timestamp int8 NOT NULL,
    last_transaction_date timestamp NOT NULL,
    snapshot_date date NOT NULL,
    "year" int2 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT wor_snapshot_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

[image]

Comment: You're missing your `group by year`, you cannot sum anything if there's nothing to sum.

Comment: I need to do SUM only on the `balance ` column based on `snapshot_date `, oh you mean year will only occur once because of the aggregation, I think I got the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error implies, you need to add the GROUP BY clause after FROM:
So the query should look like:

```
select 
'2019-09-11' as snapshot_date, 
SUM(case when snapshot_date = '2019-09-11' then balance end) as opening_balance,
SUM(case when snapshot_date = '2019-09-09' then balance end) as closing_balance,
year 
from snapshot
group by year
```

See: https://www.javatpoint.com/postgresql-group-by-clause

Comment: Damn beaten by a few seconds. Have my +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

```sql
select 
'2019-09-11' as snapshot_date, 
SUM(case when snapshot_date = '2019-09-11' then balance end) as opening_balance,
SUM(case when snapshot_date = '2019-09-09' then balance end) as closing_balance,
year 
from snapshot
group by year
```

You need to group by year to aggregate the data together to be summed.